# CAS version 4.3.0 default username and password

Tags: cas

I installed the Apereo Central Authentication Service 4.3.0, when it started, what is the default username and password of this version of CAS ? Do I need to first config it in the file of deployerConfigContext.xml ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- casuser
- Mellon

You mean you installed the SNAPSHOT right, and downloaded the source? because there is no version 4.3.0 released.